# Extract part of a NSString in Cocoa in an efficient way

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

How could I extract a part of an NSString before certain word(s):

For example:

If the keyword set of 'separators' is an NSArray of the following words "Series" and "documentary"

and if the NSStrings where

"Chain two Series documents"  <---- I'd like to extract "Chain two"

"Chain documentary documents" <---- I'd like to extract "Chain"

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to [scan strings](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000147) up to the separators that you provide it.

Someone else mentioned NSString's -componentsSeparatedByString, but that would seem inefficient if you're unconcerned about the text after the separator or if you want to check for multiple separators, based on your example.

Answer (score 1):

See the NSString method `-componentsSeparatedByString:`

Answer (score 1):

Just use Regular Expressions. They are very useful and supported starting from 10.4 !

[RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/#RegexKitLite)

There is libicucore (libicu on Tiger).

So RegexKitLite is just wrapper for system library.

Comment: So pattern for your task will look like:

^(.*?)(?:Series|documentary)